# Расстановка знаков препинания в песне Высоцкого «Вершина»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, частица

Хотелось бы узнать, как правильно расставить знаки препинания в следующих строках песни Высоцкого:
И пусть говорят(,/—) да(,) пусть говорят,
Но (—) нет, (—) никто не гибнет зря...
Так (—) лучше, чем от водки и от простуд(./!)
В сети есть разные варианты пунктуационного оформления этой песни, но везде я вижу какие-то ошибки, поэтому доверия нет ни одному варианту. Вероятно, есть какой-то официальный, но я не нашла. Больше всего меня интересует постановка знаков вокруг "да".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вряд ли можно говорить о правильности текста, так как постановка знаков здесь вариативная (авторская). Считать какое-либо издание каноническим (общепризнанным) тоже сложно, но это касается всего творческого наследия В. Высоцкого.

На эту тему есть интересная статья (2015 год), где рассказано о проблемах при работе с его текстами, а также дается перечень известных издательских групп.  За очень малыми исключениями, произведения В.С. Высоцкого опубликованы в печатном виде лишь после смерти автора. В частности, автор статьи выделил пять основных групп составителей-текстологов, а также дал перечень осуществленных ими изданий.
https://fantlab.ru/blogarticle37694

2. Мы же рассмотрим  два разных варианта оформления указанного фрагмента и проведем краткий анализ вариативных знаков.

Вариант 1. Это основной вариант, он уже указан в первом ответе, тот же текст в собрании сочинений в четырех томах. Том 2. Песни.1971–1980, изд. 2008 года.

И пусть говорят, да, пусть говорят,

Но – нет, никто не гибнет зря!

Так лучше – чем от водки и от простуд.

Вариант 2.  Сайт https://www.culture.ru/poems/19580/vershina

И пусть говорят – да, пусть говорят!

Но нет – никто не гибнет зря,

Так – лучше, чем от водки и от простуд.

Разница  между вариантами в постановке восклицательного знака и  тире. Также сомнения возникают по поводу запятой после слова «да».

(1) Восклицательный знак делит фрагмент текста на две части. Его постановка в конце второй строки представляется более убедительной, смысл всего предложения в первой части такой: Хотя многие так говорят (= что альпинисты гибнут зря), но зря никто не гибнет!

(2) Тире во всех примерах интонационное и обозначает увеличенную паузу. В стихах (а тем более в песне) меньше возможностей для произвольной расстановки пауз,  поэтому тире надо ставить там, где оно смотрится естественно в соответствии с заданной ритмикой:  Но нет – никто не гибнет зря! Так лучше – чем от водки и от простуд.

(3)  Запятая выделяет утвердительное слово «да», но частица «да» здесь тоже смотрелась бы убедительно: И пусть говорят,  да пусть говорят…
Можно считать, что фраза повторяется, но уже с частицей "да" (для большей эмоциональности и экспрессии). Согласно словарю,  частица «да» используется для придания высказыванию большей силы и выразительности.

К тому же обозначить паузу после утвердительного слова "да" при постановке запятой не представляется возможным. В песне из кинофильма "Вертикаль" ясно слышатся ударные позиции слов: И пУсть говорят, да пУсть говорят. Паузы в этом случае после "да" быть не может.

С другой стороны, можно обратить внимание на противопоставление слов ДА и НЕТ – возможно, составители руководствовались этим фактом. Высоцкий, безусловно, видел письменный текст песни, но трудно сказать, насколько его интересовала пунктуация. Поэтому нельзя исключать вероятность редакторской правки. А  каково авторское понимание смысла, судить трудно. Но все-таки попробуем предложить еще один вариант записи:

И пусть говорят, да пусть говорят,

Но нет – никто не гибнет зря!

Так лучше – чем от водки и от простуд.

В заключение заметим, что любое оформление  стихотворения  Высоцкого сложно считать авторским, каноническим и единственно правильным, если нет убедительных доказательств этого (мнения самого автора, каких-то записей и т.д.). Было бы интересно найти любые факты по этой теме.

Comment: Приветствую Вас, *Sharon*. Неподдельно рада!

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, хоть кто-то мне рад и со мной разговаривает.  Главное в русском языке (и на форуме русского языка) – это грамматика, стилистика и пунктуация!  Согласны?  Мы изучаем форму речи применительно к содержанию, а не наоборот.  А вы любите Высоцкого?  Какое-то время он был моим кумиром, а сейчас вроде бы забылось,  да вот вспомнилось. Пророческая песня, как будто не про горы, а про себя пишет. И какая любопытная  история с его текстами. Кто их правил, как их правили…

Comment: Спасибо! Я этот текст предложила дочке и ее подружкам в качестве диктанта,  летние тренировки, чтобы писать не разучились. И вот столкнулась с  такими трудностями. Мне очень хотелось обойтись без запятой после да, потому что мы сначала слушали песню - и там не было никакой паузы.

Comment: Спасибо! Было интересно,  я вообще люблю анализировать стихи. Заодно кое-что узнала о творческом наследии Высоцкого. Конечно, все считают правильным обособление "да", но мне этот вариант не кажется таким.

Answer (score 2):

У меня есть издание 1988 года, в котором пунктуация такая (Всесоюзное творческо-производственное объединение "Киноцентр"; в работе над сборником принимали участие [Ю. Тырин](http://www.bards.ru/person.php?id=5520) и Л. Ушаков):
*И пусть говорят, да, пусть говорят,

Но — нет, никто не гибнет зря!

Так лучше — чем от водки и от простуд.*

[***Да***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B0) в предложении выступает в качестве частицы, которая подтверждает ранее высказанное, имеет значение "действительно, верно, конечно". В этом случае требуется ее обособление.
Мне нравится такой "расклад знаков" — я бы ничего не стала менять.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я-то на свой вкус было оформила, без запятой - "да пусть говорят".